# javax.jws.WebService.wsdlLocation with jboss 4.2.2

Tags: java, jboss, web-services, wsdl

How specifically can you use the javax.jws.WebService.wsdlLocation in JBoss 4.2.2? (This is for an EJB3 bean deployed as a web service).

There is some documentation around that it is supported, but what exactly is the format? I have tried an http, I have tried a relative URL. How does JBoss look for it, a URL, something on the classpath of the EJB, something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at [JBWS-2206](https://jira.jboss.org/jira/browse/JBWS-2206) and related issues [JBWS-1714](https://jira.jboss.org/jira/browse/JBWS-1714) and [JBWS-1837](https://jira.jboss.org/jira/browse/JBWS-1837).

From the information I could gather, JBoss internally uses Metro (the RI) for JAX-WS. I'm not very sure about this, but it appears that Metro reads WSDLs, if provided via the wsdllocation attribute, using the classloader, thereby making META-INF/wsdl of the EJB JAR a safe choice to place WSDLs. [The example file in JBWS-2206](https://jira.jboss.org/jira/secure/attachment/12320596/example.zip) would help as a reference.

**Update**

A thorough overview on [how to provide your own WSDL is present in the JBoss forums](http://www.jboss.org/index.html?module=bb&op=viewtopic&t=104843).

**Update #2**

The JAX-WS specification, gives a better idea on why this is the case. In the section *5.2.5.3 Use of @WebService(wsdlLocation) and Metadata*, one can find the specification stating that

> The value of the wsdlLocation annotation element on an endpoint implementation class, if any, MUST
> be a relative URL. The document it points to MUST be packaged with the application. Moreover, it MUST
> follow the requirements in section 5.2.5.4 below (”Application-specified Service”).

Furthermore, it states that

> A JAX-WS implementation MUST patch the location attributes of all wsdl:import and xsd:import
> statement in local documents that point to local documents. An implementation MUST NOT patch any
> other location attributes.

defining how the generated WSDL should appear.

Comment: For EJB3, the link to JBWS-2206 did the trick. It is rather surprising that you have to reference the META-INF, but that was the hidden secret I hadn't guessed.

Comment: Yea, there are a lot of things that in JAX-WS that are not obvious at first sight. If you encounter a similar case, download a copy of the JAX-WS 2.0/2.1 specifications.

Comment: By the way, in this case, the JAX-WS 2.0 spec says - **The value of the wsdlLocation annotation element on an endpoint implementation class, if any, MUST be a relative URL. The document it points to MUST be packaged with the application. Moreover, it MUST follow the requirements in section 5.2.5.4 below (”Application-specified Service”)**

Comment: Ah, but relative to what? I saw that, but META-INF isn't relative to anything obvious. JBoss' interpretation is reasonable, I guess, but not obvious.

Comment: Yes, that's right. META-INF is not defined in the spec as the location.

Comment: And leaving that location to the JAX-WS implementation is a bit foolhardy. There's nothing preventing IBM WAS (the only JAX-WS provider that does not use Metro) from asking developers to put WSDLs in META-INF\jaxws\ or the like.

Comment: Vinnet, any insight into this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369624/jboss-4-2-2-web-service-soapaddress

Comment: Looks interesting, will give it a shot.